# axWindowsMediaPlayer event not working in not-Form class

Tags: c#, events, axwindowsmediaplayer

the axWindowsMediaPlayer has been working correctly in my Form class, now I wanted to create an abstract factory for different players and I moved the axWindowsMediaPlayer into an implementation class of that factory.
But now the playstatechanged Event isn't fired anymore, am I missing something? 
This is my initialization in the constructor of the implementation class:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1 = new AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer();
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.CreateControl();
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.BeginInit();
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.PlayStateChange += new AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange);
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.EndInit();
```

Later the event is occuring in the implementation class:

```
    private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(
    object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
    {
        if (e.newState == 8)
        {
            this.playnext(listBox);
        }
    }
```

So am I missing something, why was this working in my Winform but not in my other class?

Comment: Now it's working, the problem was that it was a VS 2010 project. I just created a new VS 2013 project and copied the files into it, now all is working as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's working, the problem was that it was a VS 2010 project. I just created a new VS 2013 project and copied the files into it, now all is working as it should.